# ASP.NET Core Web API: how can I register a value derived from the request context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I'd like to define an endpoint like this (example):

```
app.MapGet("userId", (User user) => user.id);
```

In this example, the endpoint exposed to the caller should take no parameters. The `User` object should be derived from information present in the request (e.g. in the header), but the method definition shouldn't need to know that detail - it should just be able to access `User` as a dependency.

I thought that I could accomplish this by specifying a resolution for the `User` dependency similar to this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(User), p =>
{
    var cont = p.GetService<HttpContext>();    
    return new User(cont.Request.Headers["userKey"].ToString());
});
```

However, when I run this, the `p.GetService<HttpContext>()` returns `null`.

How can I create a request-scoped dependency resolution that incorporates data from the request? Is this a good approach, but I'm just not looking for the right service? Or is this approach not going to work?

Comment: Could you create a service class with a method that returns the User model/class and inject that into your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the HttpContextAccessor

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(User), p =>
{
  var httpContextAccessor = p.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
  var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
  (...)
});
```

Comment: this works -- just don't skip the `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` line like I did ;P